# Подключение к базе без ОРМ и фреймворка c локалки

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Только начал изучать курс по MongoDb - но захотелось немного практики:
После инсталяции монги существуют 3 дефолтные базы - имеют ли они какое то критическое системное значение или их можно удалять не задумываясь?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть еще моменты:
Из командной оболочки подключение происходит корректно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот из файла `node.js` подключиться к базе корректно не удается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что необходимо прописать в параметре MongoClient что бы можно было подключится к серверу монги расположенному на локалке?
Или же необходимо использовать какой то другой параметр для локального подключения со своей операционки(Windows 10)?

```
// mongoDb.js

const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb');

const start = async () => {
    try{
        await client.connect();
    }

    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}

start();

E:\Downloads\Node\proga\node.exe E:\Progi3\vanilla-node-rest-api-master\models\mongoDb.js
E:\Progi3\vanilla-node-rest-api-master\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:280
        throw new error_1.MongoParseError(`${optionWord} ${Array.from(unsupportedOptions).join(', ')} ${isOrAre} not supported`);
        ^

MongoParseError: option gssapiservicename is not supported
    at parseOptions (E:\Progi3\vanilla-node-rest-api-master\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:280:15)
    at new MongoClient (E:\Progi3\vanilla-node-rest-api-master\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:62:63)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Progi3\vanilla-node-rest-api-master\models\mongoDb.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Comment: уберите в адресе подключения `gssapiServiceName`

Comment: Это не помогло. Но следуя этой логике удалил из кода ?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb  и после этого ошибка исчезла.
Такая реализация может считаться корректной?

Comment: а почему нет, судя из названия опций, там нет ничего критически важного

Comment: А на счет дефолтных 3-х баз данных во время установки - они критичны?
Если внедрите свою идею в ответ с кодом - поставлю вам ответ в актив(если хотите конечно)

Comment: не работал с монго, но по опыту других СУБД могу сказать, что они используют "системные" БД для хранения собственных настроек. Удалять их не лучшее решение.